# My program isn't showing 2 answers in a loop that stops only when two answers are given

Tags: python

I am trying to build a BlackJack game.

The program starts, and uses the random module to generate 2 different numbers which tells you which card you have.

- Number 1 is the value, e.g. 8
- Number 2 is the suit, e.g. 4 = Spades

The program gives me 2 cards sometimes, and the other half the time it gives me one card.

**Question:** Why is this program not working as desired?

```
types = [" of Spades", " of Diamonds", " of Clubs", " of Hearts"]
special = ["King", "Queen", "Jack", "Ace"] 
tries = 0

import random
import time

print("Welcome to BlackJack.")
time.sleep(1)

print("Let's Begin.")
time.sleep(1)

while tries < 1:
    cardnumber1 = random.randint(2, 13)
    random.shuffle(types)
    random.shuffle(special)
    cardnumber2 = random.randint(2, 13)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardnumber3 = random.randint(2, 9)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardnumber4 = random.randint(2, 9)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardtype1 = random.choice(types)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardtype2 = random.choice(types)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardtype3 = random.choice(types)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardtype4 = random.choice(types)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardspecial = random.choice(special)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)
    cardspecial2 = random.choice(special)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)

    if cardnumber1 > 10:
        print(str(cardnumber3) + cardtype1)
        tries = tries + 1
    if cardnumber2 > 10:
        print(str(cardnumber4) + cardtype2)
        tries = tries + 1
    if cardnumber1 < 9:
        print(cardspecial + cardtype3)
        tries = tries + 1
    if cardnumber2 < 9:
        print(cardspecial2 + cardtype4)
        tries = tries + 1
```

Comment: You need to fix the indentation. Re-copy your code in, highlight all of it, and hit the code `{}` button.

Comment: Try that, i've never used stackoverflow before, sorry.

Comment: `random.choice()` doesn't rely on the order of the cards, so *all* of the `random.shuffle()`s you don't make it any more random. It's like shuffling the deck twice instead of once. If you did a proper shuffle, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'll remove those, but if you run the code enough it gives you one card instead of 2. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: What happens if cardnumber1 or cardnumber2 is equal to 9 or 10?

Comment: if it hits 9, it turns into 10, a 10 is a jack.
I did this because you can't have a "one" card. A one card is an ace so I had to start with a 2.

Comment: Look at your if statements. If `cardnumber1 = rand.randint(2,13)` yields 9 or 10 none of your if statements will be satisfied.

Comment: You don't need those

    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(types)

They're redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your `if`-statements.
If any card is a 9 or a 10, while the other card is not, then you will end up with only a single card.
The reason for this is because a 9 or a 10 is not handled by any of your `if`-statements, but are excluded. Since the `while`-loop ends if any `if`-statement has been True, you end up with a single card.

So, to follow your coding closely, I think it should be the following:

```
if cardnumber1 >= 10:
    print(str(cardnumber3) + cardtype1)
    tries = tries + 1
if cardnumber2 >= 10:
    print(str(cardnumber4) + cardtype2)
    tries = tries + 1
if cardnumber1 <= 9:
    print(cardspecial + cardtype3)
    tries = tries + 1
if cardnumber2 <= 9:
    print(cardspecial2 + cardtype4)
    tries = tries + 1
```

EDIT: However, on how to improve the coding in itself, Patrick Artner's answer is very useful.

Comment: Thanks alot! I thought that was the problem at first but my mind has trouble comprehending the fact that when something is greater than something, it isn't actually it.

Comment: No problem, that is why we are here.

Answer (score 3):

You could declare your lists fully:

```
types = [" of Spades", " of Diamonds", " of Clubs", " of Hearts"]
cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
```

And create a full deck of them:

```
deck =  [ (card, typ) for card in cards for typ in types] # create tuples
print (deck)
```

To draw a card:

```
card = random.choice(deck) # will return a tuple for 1 card, 1st value is face, 2nd is typ

deck.remove(card)  # remove the card from the deck so you dont draw it again

face,typ = card # deconstruct tuple

print(face)
print(typ)
```

Outputs:

```
 [('2', ' of Spades'), ('2', ' of Diamonds'), ('2', ' of Clubs'), ('2', ' of Hearts'),
  ('3', ' of Spades'), ('3', ' of Diamonds'), ('3', ' of Clubs'), ('3', ' of Hearts'), 
  ('4', ' of Spades'), ('4', ' of Diamonds'), ('4', ' of Clubs'), ('4', ' of Hearts'), 
  ('5', ' of Spades'), ('5', ' of Diamonds'), ('5', ' of Clubs'), ('5', ' of Hearts'),
  ('6', ' of Spades'), ('6', ' of Diamonds'), ('6', ' of Clubs'), ('6', ' of Hearts'),
  ('7', ' of Spades'), ('7', ' of Diamonds'), ('7', ' of Clubs'), ('7', ' of Hearts'),
  ('8', ' of Spades'), ('8', ' of Diamonds'), ('8', ' of Clubs'), ('8', ' of Hearts'), 
  ('9', ' of Spades'), ('9', ' of Diamonds'), ('9', ' of Clubs'), ('9', ' of Hearts'),
  ('10', ' of Spades'), ('10', ' of Diamonds'), ('10', ' of Clubs'), ('10', ' of Hearts'), 
  ('Jack', ' of Spades'), ('Jack', ' of Diamonds'), ('Jack', ' of Clubs'), ('Jack', ' of Hearts'),
  ('Queen', ' of Spades'), ('Queen', ' of Diamonds'), ('Queen', ' of Clubs'), ('Queen', ' of Hearts'), 
  ('King', ' of Spades'), ('King', ' of Diamonds'), ('King', ' of Clubs'), ('King', ' of Hearts'),
  ('Ace', ' of Spades'), ('Ace', ' of Diamonds'), ('Ace', ' of Clubs'), ('Ace', ' of Hearts')]


10
 of Diamonds
```

---

```
deck = [ (card, typ) for card in cards for typ in types]
```

is called a list comprehension. It is a way to construct lists from stuff - i.e. ranges, other lists, iterators, ...

Basic syntax :

- `newList = [ str(x) for x in range(0,10)]` will use the inbuilt range(0,10) which creates numbers from 0 to 9 and makes them a string and built a list from it - Link to doku:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

I build tuples `(card, typ)` for each element in `cards` (your list) and `types` your other list).

```
[ (card, typ) for card in cards for typ in types] 
# equivalent to
deck = [] # empty list
for card in cards:
    for typ in types:
        deck.append( (card,typ) ) # create tuples and add to list
```

You could use this deck and shuffle() it once, and then deck.pop() cards from it (faster, only one shuffling needed) or draw a random card every time random.choice(deck) and then remove it from the deck.

See [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for methods on a list.

See [buildins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) - you find the `range()` in that list and can get more infos.

Comment: Oh that's really cool! I didn't know you could do that. Can you explain what the
deck =  [ (card, typ) for card in cards for typ in types] is?

Comment: @JonahBrunson Put some links and basic explanation in. List comprehension are fun, you can f.e. do stuff like `squared = [x*x for x in range(-10,11,2)]` ==> [100, 64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100] - the range() thingy is something to study as well.